# Power of AM signal

Tags: power, modulation, amplitude-modulation, amplitude

I need to calculate the power of the sidebands and the carrier.
The carrier is 10*cos(2pi10⁶t) [V] and the modulating is 3*cos(2pi10³t) [V].
The modulated signal is 10*cos(\$w_0\$t)+\$\frac{3}{2}\$*cos(\$w_0\$t+\$w_m\$t)+\$\frac{3}{2}\$*cos(\$w_0\$t-\$w_m\$t).

The furthest I can get is to \$\frac{m²(t)∗u²}{1+m²(t)∗u²}\$
But I can't find what m(t) is.

How can I calculate the percentage of power in the sidebands compared to the total AM power. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Homework with no attempt at a solution

Comment: yep I have an attemp. I get to \$\frac{m²(t)*u²}{1+m²(t) * u²}\$

Comment: @MattYoung but I can't figure out where the m(t) comes from. Not homework but exam study

Comment: Here is a clue to help you! Think about the Power Spectral Density of the signal. Were you shown how to calculate psd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result consists of three components: One for the carrier and one for each sideband. The multiplier term is the peak voltage of each.  The power in each is proportional to the square of the voltages:

10^2 : (3/2)^2 : (3/2)^2.

Then it is trivial to calculate the ratio of the powers.